# Find location of a cell's value without knowing table or column name in a sql server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find a certain table of data but I do not know the name of the table or the columns in it. I have the data in the table at hand. The database is huge do not have the patience it manually go through and look. Is there a query that can be used to search through each of the thousands of tables searching for an exact value that I have.

Comment: based on the value you have, you should be able to greatly limit the tables you should explore. I didn't DV but i find this quite odd.

Answer (score 2):

Having been working as a system admin on systems I did not develop this is an issue I face frequently.  Here is how I approach it:

1) Is there a test system and a UI you can insert the values from?  If so, do a profile trace or extended events to see where the data is going.

2) Is there a data dictionary for the product you can look through and hopefully find the table location?

3) The hardest way is to use information_Schema.columns and information_schema.tables and make educated guesses as to what the table might be named and review the data in it and see if you have it right or not.